# MySQL: Select records where COUNT 

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select 1000 customers that have placed exactly 1 order. Everything is in the Orders table.

> select * from `Order` having count(CustomerID) = 1 limit 1000

So basically all records that have only one occurence of the CustomerID in the entire table. This returns an empty result set and there are 100,000s in the table.

Comment: Are you looking for the distinct customer ID's? What value are you trying to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `GROUP` in order to (meaningfully) use the `HAVING` clause. The following works as expected:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `Order`
GROUP BY
    CustomerID
HAVING
    COUNT(CustomerID) = 1
LIMIT 1000
```

---

**UPDATE**
Adding `WHERE` (see comments):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `Order`
WHERE
    Language = 'EN'
GROUP BY
    CustomerID
HAVING
    COUNT(CustomerID) = 1
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Works! However if I add a WHERE Language = "EN" I get a syntax error. You know why?

Comment: @stef How do you add it? `... FROM \`Order\` WHERE ... GROUP BY ...` should work. See updated answer.

Comment: @stef Do note that `WHERE` is executed as a condition on the query (before aggregate functions), whereas `HAVING` is performed afterwards since it targets aggregated data (e.g., `COUNT()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `Order`
GROUP BY CustomerID 
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) = 1 
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select count(CustomerID) as counter ,o.* from Order o
group by CustomerID having  counter  = 1  limit 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Add group by to query for correct output, e.g:

select * 
from Order 
group by CustomerID
having count(CustomerID) = 1 
limit 1000

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CustomerID FROM `Order` GROUP BY CustomerID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 LIMIT 1000